# AltBeacon Transmitter/Scanner

Tags: altbeacon

developers!

I would like to know whether is it possible for AltBeacon Transmitter Android App to detect if a Scanner Android App is listening to the Transmitter? If it is possible, how do I start?

I have attached an image for a clearer picture of my question. [Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egpkE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A beacon transmitter is a transmit-only device that emits packets with no knowledge of whether any receiver is listening. **It is  not possible to know directly if a receiver is present.**

This is equivalent to an over-the-air television broadcast.  The transmitter sends the signal with no knowledge of there is anybody with a television turned on and  tuned to  the proper frequency.

in both cases in order to find out if anybody is listening you must build another feedback mechanism.  With Bluetooth beacons, it is typical to build a mobile app to call a server to tell it the advertisement has been received.